# Fetch specific data within API using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

How can I fetch the prize using JavaScript?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Do you mean, how you get to that item in the object?

Comment: @waz yes that's what I meant.

Comment: you want to get it w/o specifying which key i.g `1`, `2`?

Comment: why my answer set not accept as.

Comment: I can't Look at the predictions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok let me assume you want to get the `prize` w/o specifying which level is it either level 1, level 2. and you want to display it inside a table,
here is a good way on how to iterate thru it.

```js
let data = {
  name: 'name',
  method: 'method',
  levels: {
    1: {
      count: "count",
      prize: 123
    },
    2: {
      count: "count",
      prize: 456
    }
  }
}

for (let level of Object.keys(data.levels)) {
  console.log(data.levels[level].prize);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to retrieve the item of the object, try:

```
var prize = data.levels.1.prize
```

Another way to retrieve items from objects is:

```
let prize = data.levels['1'].prize
```

I hope this puts you in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = {
  name: 'name',
  method: 'method',
  levels: {
    1: {
      count: "count",
      prize: 123
    }
  }
}

console.log('aaa', data['levels'][1]['prize']);
```

```html
Check console log
```

Comment: why not `data.levels[1].prize`

Comment: I  resent develop angular that is reason

Comment: what happen here?